# Will change stream work for time series collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, time-series, changestream

I have a requirement where we need to use change stream to track the data insertions to Time Series collection.
I tried to create a change stream listener to that collection. But it is not working.

I tried this. This is a sample code that can listen to all changes in the database collections, I am just logging them in Audit Collection.

```
  const dbWatch = db.watch();
  await dbWatch.on('change', async (next) => {
    console.log('Received change event:', next);
    resumeToken = next._id;
    let insertDocument = getInsertDocument(next);
    switch(next.operationType){
      case "insert":
        insertDocument.Operation = next.operationType;
        insertDocument.Description = next.fullDocument;
        break;
      case "update":
        insertDocument.Operation = next.operationType;
        insertDocument.Description = next.updateDescription;
        break;
      }
    await AuditColl.insertOne(insertDocument);
  });
```

But this is not working for Time Series Collections, I am unable to receive them even though they are being inserted.

I am not sure but I even read that it is not supported in MongoDB.
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/collection-watch-for-time-series/127656
Please confirm

Comment: Another link that tells the same thing: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/?_ga=2.154133552.982453121.1677513531-1460821068.1671237631#unsupported-features

Comment: Yes You are right. It is not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found the answer after thorough research and discussions with resource persons.

As on March 2023 MongoDB, Change Streams is Not Supported for Time Series Collections in MongoDB.
[image]

Here are my References:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/collection-watch-for-time-series/127656
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-timeseries-change-stream-support-or-any-alternative/192106